How to pass a variable list to another play with different hosts
I want to append all the hostnames into a list and pass it to another play with different host-group (remote server) where it searches for a file with a pattern. I am trying an Ansible playbook -
- name: Begin
  hosts: cisco
  tasks:
    - name: Initializing an empty list where I will try to append the hostnames
      set_fact:
        my_string: []

- name: Append info
  hosts: cisco
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Append hostname to list (appending is not working, not sure how to pass inventory_hostnames recursively)
      set_fact:
        my_string: "{{ my_strings + [inventory_hostname] }}"

- hosts: remoteserver
  tasks:
    - name: Find stored configuration file on remote server by passing value item from loop (Ansible can not find this variable my_string)
      find:
        paths: /Config/ansible-backups/
        patterns: "{{ item }}-config-*.txt"
      register: stored_configs
      loop: "{{ hostvars['cisco']['my_string'] }}"


As can be seen, the list my_string is not working as intended and I am not able to pass the list to second part. I am using version 2.10.17. Any suggestions how to proceed?

For an inventory file example.ini with content of
[inventory:children]
switches
servers

[switches]
one.example.com
two.example.com

[servers]
three.example.com
four.example.com

a minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: servers
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: On Remote Servers, passing value item from loop
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}-config-*.txt"
      loop: "{{ groups['switches'] }}"

called via
ansible-playbook --inventory example.ini inventory.yml

will result into an output of
TASK [On Remote Servers, pass value item from loop] *******
ok: [three.example.com] => (item=one.example.com) =>
  msg: one.example.com-config-*.txt
ok: [three.example.com] => (item=two.example.com) =>
  msg: two.example.com-config-*.txt
ok: [four.example.com] => (item=one.example.com) =>
  msg: one.example.com-config-*.txt
ok: [four.example.com] => (item=two.example.com) =>
  msg: two.example.com-config-*.txt


Simple, straightforward and effective. Thank you. Worked like a charm. Curious though, if I would have continued down the line of my previous approach , like making a list and passing the list in the next play, what was I doing wrong? Well I am starting in Ansible, so it would help knowing..things.

"If I would have continued down the line of my previous approach ... what was I doing wrong?", in my point of view, "asking about an attempted solution rather than describing the actual problem", just the description of your Use Case and what you really tried to achieve. Also do not program, think declarative and describe the Configuration in the Desired State.

Ok great, the very first point "Ansible is not Python. " gave me the gist

For example, given the below inventory for testing
shell> cat hosts
[cisco_1]
host_a
nost_b

[cisco_2]
host_c
nost_d

[remote]
remote_x


Take a look at the Ansible Special Variables. Quoting:


ansible_play_hosts_all: List of all the hosts that were targeted by the play


ansible_play_name: The name of the currently executed play.

Test the special variables
- name: Begin
  hosts: cisco_1
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          ansible_play_name: {{ ansible_play_name }}
          ansible_play_hosts_all: {{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}
      run_once: true

- name: Append info
  hosts: cisco_2
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          ansible_play_name: {{ ansible_play_name }}
          ansible_play_hosts_all: {{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}
      run_once: true

gives (abridged)
ok: [host_a] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_play_name: Begin
    ansible_play_hosts_all: ['host_a', 'nost_b']

ok: [host_c] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_play_name: Append info
    ansible_play_hosts_all: ['host_c', 'nost_d']


Take a look at the Ansible Playbook Keywords. Quoting:


run_once: Boolean that will bypass the host loop, forcing the task to attempt to execute on the first host available and afterward apply any results and facts to all active hosts in the same batch.

The most important and useful part is that this will "apply any results and facts to all active hosts".
Please test it
- name: Begin
  hosts: cisco_1
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_hosts: "{{ my_hosts | d({}) | combine(this_hosts) }}"
      vars:
        this_hosts: "{{ {ansible_play_name: ansible_play_hosts_all} }}"
      run_once: true

- name: Append info
  hosts: cisco_2
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_hosts: "{{ my_hosts | d({}) | combine(this_hosts) }}"
      vars:
        this_hosts: "{{ {ansible_play_name: ansible_play_hosts_all} }}"
      run_once: true

- hosts: remote
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostvars[groups.cisco_1.0].my_hosts
    - debug:
        var: hostvars[groups.cisco_2.0].my_hosts

gives (abridged)
ok: [remote_x] => 
  hostvars[groups.cisco_1.0].my_hosts:
    Begin:
    - host_a
    - nost_b

ok: [remote_x] => 
  hostvars[groups.cisco_2.0].my_hosts:
    Append info:
    - host_c
    - nost_d


Take a look at Information about Ansible: magic variables. Quoting:


With hostvars, you can access variables defined for any host in the play, at any point in a playbook

You can see hosts keep my_hosts from their plays only. Use the filter json_query and get them all
  my_hosts: "{{ hostvars | json_query('*.my_hosts') }}" 

gives
  my_hosts:
  - Begin:
    - host_a
    - nost_b
  - Begin:
    - host_a
    - nost_b
  - Append info:
    - host_c
    - nost_d
  - Append info:
    - host_c
    - nost_d

Filter unique items
  my_hosts: "{{ hostvars | json_query('*.my_hosts') | unique }}"

gives
  my_hosts:
  - Begin:
    - host_a
    - nost_b
  - Append info:
    - host_c
    - nost_d

This list provides you with complete information about hosts in plays. If you "want to append all the hostnames into a list" the below declaration
  all_hosts: "{{ my_hosts | json_query('[].*') | flatten }}"

gives what you want
  all_hosts:
  - host_a
  - nost_b
  - host_c
  - nost_d




Example of a complete playbook for testing

- name: Begin
  hosts: cisco_1
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_hosts: "{{ my_hosts | d({}) | combine(this_hosts) }}"
      vars:
        this_hosts: "{{ {ansible_play_name: ansible_play_hosts_all} }}"
      run_once: true

- name: Append info
  hosts: cisco_2
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_hosts: "{{ my_hosts | d({}) | combine(this_hosts) }}"
      vars:
        this_hosts: "{{ {ansible_play_name: ansible_play_hosts_all} }}"
      run_once: true

- hosts: remote
  vars:
    my_hosts: "{{ hostvars | json_query('*.my_hosts') | unique }}"
    # my_hosts: "{{ hostvars | json_query('*.my_hosts') }}"
    all_hosts: "{{ my_hosts | json_query('[].*') | flatten }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostvars[groups.cisco_1.0].my_hosts
    - debug:
        var: hostvars[groups.cisco_2.0].my_hosts
    - debug:
        var: my_hosts
    - debug:
        var: all_hosts


The simplified playbook below gives the same result

- name: Begin
  hosts: cisco_1
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_hosts: "{{ {ansible_play_name: ansible_play_hosts_all} }}"
      run_once: true

- name: Append info
  hosts: cisco_2
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_hosts: "{{ {ansible_play_name: ansible_play_hosts_all} }}"
      run_once: true

- hosts: remote
  vars:
    all_hosts: "{{ hostvars | json_query('*.my_hosts[].*') | flatten | unique }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: all_hosts


This can be further simplified

- name: Begin
  hosts: cisco_1
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
      run_once: true

- name: Append info
  hosts: cisco_2
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
      run_once: true

- hosts: remote
  vars:
    all_hosts: "{{ hostvars | json_query('*.my_hosts') | flatten | unique }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: all_hosts



Woww, spot on, thanks a lot. This was really helpful Sir.
